# Center TextView between Button and TextView?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:text="@string/inf" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/ben" />

                <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="18sp"
         />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"          
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/verifica" />

         <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="330dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="18sp"
         />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Running the application on my Nexus `TextView3` looks good, centered between the `TextView2` and `Button`, but on other phones do not.

Do you have ideas on how I can center it between the second `TextView` and the `Button`? And to insert a `ScrollView`?

Answer (score 0):

See following code. It may helps you.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum = "5" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_weight = "1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:text="@string/inf" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_weight = "1
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/ben" />

                <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight = "1
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="18sp"
         />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight = "1
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"          
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/verifica" />

         <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight = "1
        android:layout_marginTop="330dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="18sp"
         />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]Scrollview only supports a single child take this into consideration, Here is your layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/inf"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="TextView 2"
                android:textSize="28sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/verifica" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="TextView 3"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="330dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>]![enter image description here][2]
```